# Is there a model of ZFC such that $\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega+2}$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

By Easton's theorem, it is consistent with ZFC that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega+1}$ holds, and if we assume $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega+1}$ then
$$\aleph_{\omega+1}\le 2^{\aleph_0}\le \aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0}\le \aleph_{\omega+1}^{\aleph_0} =(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega+1}$$
So it is consistent with ZFC that $\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega+1}$, and I conjecture that $\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega+2}$ is consistent with ZFC. But how to prove it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The (significantly) harder question is whether you can have $2^{\aleph_\omega}=\aleph_{\omega+2}$ while requiring that $\aleph_\omega$ is strong limit, or even that $\mathsf{GCH}$ holds below $\aleph_\omega$.

Comment: @Andres: That's Gitik's work, right? That from a measurable with $o(\kappa)=\kappa^{++}$ we can have such a result? (I'm probably screwing up at least one of the details...)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes. Well, the result is originally Magidor's, from stronger assumptions (at the level of supercompactness), extending earlier work of Silver, who obtained from those assumptions models where there is a measurable $\kappa$ with $2^\kappa>\kappa^+$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila After Magidor, Woodin saw how to obtain $\mathsf{GCH}$ below $\aleph_\omega$, and $2^{\aleph_\omega}=\aleph_{\omega+2}$,  from the existence of measurable cardinals satisfying a largeness condition (the existence of a $\kappa^++$-canonical function, in a certain sense). Woodin proved that the same assumption suffices to get models of $o(\kappa)=\kappa^{++}$. Gitik then showed that from $o(\kappa)=\kappa^{++}$ one could recover Woodin's condition. He also showed that violations of $\mathsf{SCH}$ give models of $o(\kappa)=\kappa^{++}$, so one gets equiconsistency here.

Comment: @Andres: Thanks. History of set theory is fascinating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Easily (if one is familiar with forcing). Start with a model of $\sf GCH$. Now force that for every $\alpha\in\omega\cup\{\omega+1\}$:

$$2^{\aleph_\alpha}=\aleph_{\omega+2}$$

Then we have the wanted equality, by the same considerations as in your question.

(In fact, if one starts with $\sf GCH$ then we only need to force $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega+2}$, the rest follows.)